I can't commit my vscode files changes to repository
I can not commit and push my code files to github repositories
To commit, First of all I made new js file in vscode and commit and it is successful in vscode
code kungfu.js
but when I visit my github repository there are no new file(Kungfu.js)
there are ony README.md
Some webiste coders say that I should make global username and email equall to local username and email. so I tried also this
git config --globall-
But still I can not commit to github
so I tried git push origin master
but error said I need authentication
git clone also does not work
I trid also add repository e-mail to vscode
git remote also does not work
Some say it needs token from github website
I made token but vscoode does not ask ID and Password
Some said that I changed my account from my window consol panel, but there are no git account in my console panel
some say I need to use code 'git config --global --unset credential.helper' but it does not work also...
could you help me?
branch names are same 'master' not a main

Are you getting any error messages from Git when you try these commands? If you can't see kungfu.js in your directory, is that because you need to use Visual Studio Code to save the file to the correct directory? If you've done that, what it is the output of the git status command?

when I do git status I can see many deledted and modifed files and added files
